# How do I run gVim in a single instance per desktop workspace on linux?

Tags: gvim, tabbed-user-interface

I like running gVim in a single instance, i.e. a single gui window with separate tabs for each file I'm editing.

I also run a linux desktop environment that has multiple desktop workspaces.  E.g. GNOME, KDE or Xfce.

I would like to have a single instance of gVim per desktop workspace.

I currently alias `gvim` to `gvim --remote-tab-silent`.  Unfortunately this create a single instance (gui window) which has tabs for all of the files open in gVim from all of my workspaces.

As each workspace I use is for a different git branch it's easy to get confused as to which branch a file I'm editing is in from.

Comment: Can you just change your alias to `gvim --remote-tab-silent --servername [Workspace name]`?

Comment: (Not that it’s super relevant) but how do you manage to have each workspace be a different branch? Are you using git-worktree for that?

Comment: I have multiple git workspaces.  Each of them is on a different branch.  I work on each git 'workspace' in a separate desktop 'workspace'.  [Sorry about overloading the term 'workspace'.

Comment: I haven't used --servername before.  But this looks like it will work.  Any idea how I find out the workspace name?  I'll search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a function for this works

```
function gv () { 
  WS=`xprop -root -notype _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | awk '{print $3}'`;
  gvim --servername $WS --remote-tab-silent $@
 }
```

Note that tab completion doesn't work for me for the function so I alias something to this function.

xprop ... returns the workspace number in column 3
awk extracts just column 3